# Why is this summon command not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have Minecraft v1.11 and am trying this command to summon fallingsand but it is not working. Why?

Command:

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/fill ~ ~-1 ~-1 ~ ~50 ~-1 redstone_block},Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Block:redstone_block,Time:1}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity IDs have changed in 1.11. See: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Entity_IDs

You need to change the summoned entity's ID and ID of the passenger:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ {Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/fill ~ ~-1 ~-1 ~ ~50 ~-1 redstone_block},Passengers:[{id:falling_block,Block:redstone_block,Time:1}]}
```